# NaTcl on Google Chrome

Tags: linux, google-chrome, tcl

I was wondering if NaTcl still works on current versions of google-chrome. I am using google chrome version 28. I managed to get NaCl to work, using [the tutorial](https://developers.google.com/native-client/devguide/tutorial), but I have been unable to get NaTcl to work, using [this guide](http://wiki.tcl.tk/28211). According to that page, NaTcl only worked for google chrome version 10 and 11, but that information didn't seem to be up-to-date, so I wanted to make sure. When I go to [this page](http://wiki.tcl.tk/_natcl/balls.html) to check, I get a NO-STATUS error.

Comment: You ought to get into contact with the author of NaTcl directly; I don't think he answers things on Stack Overflow normally…

Comment: I contacted him directly, and he said that the NaCl API with the JS engine has switched from synchronous to asynchronous since then and he hasn't had the time to do the necessary adaptations